# ArcObjects running in Addin slower?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcobjects, c#, performance, add-in

I have created a class library which does some geoprocessing. The addin calls a class that is an async process. I have ensured the thread is STA and the arcobjects are thread safe (ie. not passed from the addin). All arcobjects are created within the thread.

Because this is a class library I wrapped it in a winforms UI and also as an addin. Both sets of code are exactly the same and test were performed using the exact same data. Both the winforms and addin complete the code with the desired results and no memory leaks are evident. For the case of the addin there is no interaction with the map period at this point and there are no mapping or display elements in the winforms code either.

the only UI updates are the update of a progress dialog in both the addin and UI. The addin is using a dockable window (user control ui).

The issue I am seeing is when the library is called from the addin, code execution is 5x slower than the same code called through the winforms application.

Any ideas on where I might look to see why this is occurring?

Comment: Are you using any arcobjects [singletons](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//00010000043p000000)?

Comment: Yes, a quick look at the list and I am using a few workspacefactory objects to open my featureclasses independant of ArcMap so they are created within the thread. I am creating two workspacefactories (for my input and output) then looping and caching data locally using an inmemmoryworkspace which I use a factory to create. Should I create the inmemoryworkspacefactory only once? I should mention the code doesn't fail and is slow only when executed within the addin.

Comment: Are you creating using `Activator.CreateInstance`, or with `new` ?

Comment: I am (or was) using the new. I am updating now to try the Activator.CreateInstance method.

Comment: I updated the code (thanks for pointing that out) but don't see a real difference with the update.

Comment: Hmm, what happens if you comment out the part that updates the progress dialog?

Comment: no difference commenting out progress dialog. it's weird because even code not using arcobjects are also executed faster in the winforms app vs. the addin. it's like all code execution is slowing down when run through an addin vs. what seems to be possible in the winforms app. now the winforms app is just a simple wrapper and doesn't use nearly the resource ArcMap would so wonder if there is something with that.

Comment: You are running your code in ArcMap, which is a single thread application, so you need to 'share' your thread will all sorts of events raised and consumed by ArcMap. As a singleton object you're not sharing the thread with ArcMap. If you launched your process on a separate thread from ArcMap you wouldn't see as marked a difference.

Answer (score 1):

When comparing both versions, you may be timing more than just the geoprocessing time.

Perhaps there are some initialization procedures running in your standalone application that are already performed in ArcMap at startup e.g. creation of MxDocument object, license checkout, creation of scratch GDB, etc.

There could also be a difference in the .NET Framework version used in ArcMap and your desktop application (Although I don't see that causing a 5x slowdown).